# Is there a way to track player-defined missions in Kerbal Space Program?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I've played Kerbal Space Program now to the point that I'm no longer really interested in the pre-defined missions in Career Mode. For awhile, I want to just focus on exploring space *my way*. This doesn't mean I don't want to perform missions, it just means that I want to be the one defining the parameters.

Unfortunately, now I don't have any way to track my missions in-game. I often find myself, after some time away from the game, loading up KSP and having to spend my first several minutes just trying to figure out where I left off. During this process, I need to answer questions like:

- What spacecraft do I have out there, and what's their current status?
- Why did I put those things out there in the first place?
- What am I supposed to be doing with them next?
- Did I leave any of my spacecraft in a condition which would prevent me from doing what I wanted to do with them?

This problem would only be compounded should I ever choose to run more than one mission at a time. Right now, I'm avoiding that just so I don't have to worry about forgetting the status/objectives of one mission while I'm spending time working on another - let alone remembering all of them when I walk away from the computer.

I could simply work around this by jotting stuff down in Notepad or something similar, and popping that open whenever I'm running KSP. However this would be a very manual process which breaks game immersion and presents a number of other undesirable inconveniences and/or failure points. So, I'm instead looking for a solution to implement player-defined mission tracking in-game.

**Bare-Minimum Requirements**

- Enhance the KSC Tracking Station and/or provide a separate in-game interface to include the following minimum details:

  - Spacecraft name
  - Player-defined notes
- Implement all features in-game without need for player to manually launch or manage data in an external app.

**Preferred Additional Features**

- Allow player to define missions.
- Allow player to assign spacecraft to missions.

  - Allow filtering of spacecraft list by mission.
  - Allow filtering of Tracking Station and/or Map views by mission.
- Provide "to-do list" type interface for player-defined mission objectives.
- Allow player to define success milestones which automatically track mission progress.

  - Example 1: Check off a mission objective when [spacecraft] has achieved an orbit matching [orbit parameters] within [acceptable margin].
  - Example 2: Check off a mission objective when [spacecraft] has landed on [body] within [range] latitude and [range] longitude.
- Allow the player to define failure milestones which automatically alert to conditions that will prevent mission completion.

  - Example 1: Fail the mission if [critical components] are damaged on [spacecraft].
  - Example 2: Fail the mission if [specified Kerbal(s)] die.
  - Example 3: Fail the mission if [spacecraft] trajectory goes beyond [orbit parameters] before [specified objective or success milestone] is completed.
- Option to pop up a missions status overview on KSP game load.

  - Should include list of active missions, associated spacecraft statuses, and next objective/milestone.
- Archive of completed/failed missions.

Answer (score 6):

you are in luck something already exists: [In game notes / notepad / checklist v0.10.1 26/10/14](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/55625-0-25-In-game-notes-notepad-checklist-v0-10-1-26-10-14)

Features:

- Take in game notes anywhere.
- Multiple notes support.
- Multiple directories support.
- List/open/delete/save notes dialogs.
- Optional Toolbar integration.
- Movable windows with position save.
- Configurable keybind, font size and mouse button.
- Autosave open note when scene changes or game quit, even on ALT + F4.
- Ship's log.
- Unity default skin and KSP skin.
- Includes workaround for linux version bug: http://bugs.kerbalspaceprogram.com/issues/1230.

Comment: Looks like it's missing a lot of my nice-to-haves, but should be a good fit for the bare minimum and then some.

Answer (score 5):

[Kerbal Alarm Clock](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/threads/24786-0-25-0-Kerbal-Alarm-Clock-v3-0-1-0-(Oct-26)) can be very helpful here. Just set an alarm for when a craft needs attention, such as maneuver nodes, SOI changes, interplanetary transfer windows...

For notes which are not really an alarm you could still abuse it by setting an alarm in the far future.

[image: kerbal alarm clock screenshot]

Comment: A little hacky, but a nice idea. I was thinking some of Alarm Clock's functions would be good to have integrated into the process as well, but hadn't considered it as the primary tool. However, keeping long-term notes by "setting an alarm in the far future" might end up a bit more cumbersome than it sounds. Assuming the game/plugin keeps track of alarm counters as an unsigned 32-bit integer value representing seconds (just a guess, with very little justification of basis), the maximum duration would be around 466 years. It seems that would be easy to inadvertently fast-forward through.

Comment: @Iszi it uses doubles for storing when the alarm should happen

Comment: @ratchetfreak Well, that *is* a horse of *substantially* different color.